# Let $G$ be a nilpotent group, $H\subsetneq G$. How to prove $H \subsetneq N$, where $N$ is a normalizer of $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group, $H\subsetneq G$. How to prove $H \subsetneq N$, where $N$ is a normalizer of $H$?

I tried to use induction. It's easy to show the property works when nilpotency is equal to $1$, but I've got stuck moving further.

Comment: Please don't repost [closed questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3835662/10513). Instead, you should edit them to improve them.

Comment: @user1729 ok, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: since $G$ is nilpotent it has a central series $\{N_i: 0 \leq i \leq r \}$ and $N_0=1 \subseteq H$ and $N_r=G$ which is not contained in $H$ obviously. So, there must be an index $i$ with $N_i \subseteq H$ and $N_{i+1} \nsubseteq H$. Try to show $N_{i+1} \subseteq N_G(H)$. Then $H \lt N_G(H)$.

> Observe that we have a central series here, and centers are always contained in normalizers, so $$N_{i+1}/N_i \subseteq Z(G/N_i) \subseteq N_{G/N_i}(H/N_i) \subseteq N_G(H)/N_i.$$ It follows that $N_{i+1} \subseteq N_G(H)$.

Comment: I tried to work with commutators. [G,N$_{i+1}$] $\subseteq$ N$_i$ $\subseteq$ $_G$() then N$_{i+1}^G$ N$_{i+1}$ $\subseteq$ $_G$() . Am I going the right way?

Comment: Sort of right track, but see spoiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why do we have N$_{G/N_i}$(H/N$_i$) $\subseteq$ N$_G$(H)/N$_i$ ? Is it some property I forgot about? :)

Comment: No this is just computations in a factor group: let overbar $\bar{.}$ denote modding out by $N_i$. Let $\bar{g} \in N_{\overline{G}}(\overline{H})$. Then $\bar{g}^{-1}\bar{h}\bar{g}=\bar{k}$, for some $k \in H$. That is, $g^{-1}hg=kn$ for some $n \in N_i$. But $N_i \subseteq H$, and this implies $g \in N_G(H)$. Hope it is clear now!